# Explanation on Electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics

If we rub a plastic scale repeatedly with our dry hair,then the hair stand up and separate from each other. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

We have $2$ kinds of  charges, positive and negative. Basics  of electrostatics is that like charges repel and opposite charges attract.

When you rub hair with an insulated object like plastic scale, some of the charge separates from the hair and moves to the outside surface of the plastic scale. Since the hair was neutral to begin with, it will acquire a certain charge. When neighboring hair strands have acquired the same sign of charge, then repulsion forces is exerted on each other. This is why you see hair standing up or separating from each other.

Also notice that the plastic scale would have acquired a net charge of same magnitude but opposite sign to that of on the hair. So if you now bring the  plastic scale close to the same strands of hair, you will see them getting attracted and moving towards each other.

[More stuff to read](http://www.charlesedisonfund.org/experiments/HTMLexperiments/Chapter9/9-Expt2/p1.html)